# In MySQL, how does the length of blob data correlate to size of its packet in bytes?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to deal with a database which has a table of longblobs that are not readable using MySQL (5.6.36).

With a max_allowed_packet of 1024MiB , I cannot select the contents of a column that has a length of 26840023 (~25MiB).

```
mysql> select bid, length(batch) from batch where bid = 32;
+-----+---------------+
| bid | length(batch) |
+-----+---------------+
|  32 |      26840023 |
+-----+---------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE variable_name = 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+------------+
| Variable_name      | Value      |
+--------------------+------------+
| max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
+--------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select batch from batch where bid = 32 limit 1;
ERROR 2020 (HY000): Got packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes
```

While this is not my database and I don't think I would ever store this sort of data in MySQL personally, I'm trying to understand the relationship between the max_allowed_packet limit and actually retrieving that information.

It seems peculiar to me that a column with a length of ~25MiB would require nearly 40 times the bytes to express its contents. Am I misunderstanding what's going on here? Is there an appropriate max_allowed_packet for any given length of blob data, or is there no reliable correlation there?

My assumption has always been that the length is not an exact amount of bytes (certain characters may require more bytes to represent), but (at least) 40 bytes per character length is unexplainable to me. Is there some way to determine what an appropriate max_allowed_packet would be for a given blob value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The packet will indeed have (about) 25MB. The problem here is (most likely) that both the server and the client have their own setting for *max_allowed_packet*. `show variables` will only display the server setting. According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet)

> When you change the message buffer size by changing the value of the max_allowed_packet variable, you should also change the buffer size on the client side if your client program permits it. [...] mysql and mysqldump have defaults of 16MB and 24MB, respectively. They also enable you to change the client-side value by setting max_allowed_packet on the command line or in an option file.

The effective allowed packetsize (which you unfortunately cannot query for) will be determined by the lower value of either server or client, so set the value in the config file (under `[mysql]`) or the command line.

For other clients you might not need to adjust it, because

> The default max_allowed_packet value built in to the client library is 1GB.

Comment: That's a really good answer. I for some reason hadn't considered that the same variables would be specified differently for different uses like that. Tricky! Thank you.